# Random internet drops on new Skylake build

Tags: networking, connection, latency

I just finished my new Skylake build and I have random internet loss. While browsing the page sometimes get stuck, Facebook chat disconnects or downloads are quitting. However the internet icon on Windows 10 says I'm connected.

**Video of problem**
Note: sometimes pages stay completely blank too, or upon posting a form, the page keeps loading but doesnt do anything. Wasn't able to capture that.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vtwbIYSemz8

**What I've tried already:**

- Reinstalled windows
- Disabled EEE Power Management on my Adapter
- Resetted router
- Restarted PC
- Changed to Google DNS (seem to have fixed it, but this morning drops again)
- Firewall off doesn't affect problem
- Tested on Live Linux USB, had the problem too, only far less apparant
- **Future tests:** Connect directly to incoming line with new build & other pc

Using the ethernet adapter from my motherboard: MSI Krait Z170A

**Other things that I notice:**

- Page browsing is okay, sometimes it takes ages to load when clicked on a link or is "stuck"
- Sometimes it loads very slowly, whilst I'm able to download other files (was downloading Ubuntu when this happened)
- Happens in both Chrome & Firefox
- Able to play multiplayer games without dropping out (so UDP is fine, I guess it only affects TCP)
- It actually looks more like "latency" than no internet. Since another page can load perfectly while other pages having trouble to open. When I press enter again, to do a new HTTP request, it mostly fixes the problem... but it's annoying
- Gaming, download large files, uploading video's doesn't seem to be a problem.

**A simple traceroute shows this**

```
C:\Users\Jesse>tracert google.com

Tracing route to google.com [2a00:1450:400c:c0a::66]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

1 <1 ms <1 ms <1 ms 2a02:1811:cc1f:f200:5e35:3bff:fe0b:6386
2 * * * Request timed out.
3 * * * Request timed out.
4 16 ms 14 ms 18 ms 2a02:1800:0:1:206:2100:0:3
5 27 ms 68 ms 17 ms ae0.anr11.ip6.gtt.net [2001:668:0:3::3000:1b1]
6 24 ms 41 ms 18 ms xe-4-3-0.ams60.ip6.gtt.net [2001:668:0:2::1:4a42]
7 17 ms 50 ms 21 ms as15169.ams10.ip6.gtt.net [2001:668:0:3::6000:5a2]
8 21 ms 14 ms 19 ms 2001:4860::1:0:87aa
9 30 ms 25 ms 23 ms 2001:4860::8:0:519f
10 41 ms 38 ms 38 ms 2001:4860::8:0:83d2
11 39 ms 33 ms 39 ms 2001:4860::2:0:a949
12 * * * Request timed out.
13 42 ms 39 ms 39 ms wl-in-x66.1e100.net [2a00:1450:400c:c0a::66]

Trace complete.
```

**Ping test 32 bytes to my webserver**

```
Ping statistics for 188.166.107.179:
    Packets: Sent = 1376, Received = 1376, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 13ms, Maximum = 84ms, Average = 21ms
```

**Ping test 11500 bytes to my webserver**

```
Ping statistics for 188.166.107.179:
    Packets: Sent = 869, Received = 863, Lost = 6 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 26ms, Maximum = 76ms, Average = 32ms
```

What do you suggest doing? I only found one driver on the MSI site The drivers for my Intel I219-V aren't even online on the intel download site. Could it be that I have to replace my motherboard or should this be a software issue?

Comment: I'd first try and isolate the problem to see if is your computer or internet connection.  Do you have access to another connection? (i.e. 4G or neighbours Wi-Fi).  Is there another PC in the household?

Comment: @albal I tried many devices already. Also on my Chromebook. I seem to have the problem too there, but it's far less happening there than on my new build. So I'm not sure yet if it's the same. Creating a video right now, which shows the problem.

Comment: Okay so it is happening on more than one device, so it's not your new build.  You PC is probably doing lot more than the Chromebook is doing so if the network is being utilised more any drops will be more apparent to you.  There is a large ping variance at hop 4 and onward which would suggest that part of GTT's network is heavily loaded.  The only thing you can really do is get in touch with your ISP or seek out the forums for your ISP.  Beware though if you don't explain you are gaming and they are actually throttling they might prioritise your web experience in lieu of real time applications

Comment: @albal Thanks. Forgot to add that gaming, uploading & downloading files aren't a problem. Or at least I didn't have any problems with it. It more on opening webpages and clicking links. I made a [video on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vtwbIYSemz8) that shows what I'm experiencing.

Comment: @albal sometimes pages stay blank for quite a while too

Comment: I suggest the first thing you do is the most basic network test which is to run a continuous ping.

Comment: @qasdfdsaq That I did too. To my own server, out of 2000 pings I got one that failed and a few that took over 100ms. Not much to worry about I think.

Comment: Well we can't tell you if you don't post the results. Nonetheless, I suspect the issue lies with IPv6 or MTU.

Comment: @qasdfdsaq How can I show you the results? Is there any scientific way to ping so you have enough data to analyse? Just did a live ubuntu test run. It seems fine there, although I had the same issue again, but far less apparant than on Windows.

Comment: @qasdfdsaq added ping tests.

Comment: You seem to be missing about 2000 lines. The latency seems unstable but again, without the full results I can't tell. Nonetheless, my previous suspicions still stand.